# How do I determine the PID of my python program if there is more then one python program running?

Tags: linux, bash, python, pid

I have two python programs running on my system, say they are called program `x` and program `y`.

I want to get the pid of program `y`, but not `x` for my bash script. When using `pgrep python`, I get the pid of both of them and don't know which is which.

Any ideas how I tell the difference between the two in a bash script?

Comment: I don't have voting privileges yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can match against the argument list by using the `-f` switch to `pgrep` (try `man pgrep` to read more).

```
pgrep -f x
```

should yield only program `x` and

```
pgrep -f y
```

respectively only program `y`.

As an alternative, if `x` and `y` are not unique enough and end in too many rows, you could use `ps` and `grep` to have more options

```
ps ax | grep 'python x' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
```

This will

- list all relevant processes
- grep for the ones with `python x` in it. In here you might need to add a path specifier like `python ./path/to/x`
- remove the grep command itself from the list of matched processes
- print only the first column, which is the pid.